# Does it make sense too have a column dependent on the total number of row in another table too improve speed?

Tags: mysql

I have an application that requires the total number of interactions.

I have two tables. TABLE1 has a `total` column. TABLE2 has all of the interactions (columns) that update frequently. It has a column like `didInteract`. It is a 1:M relationship between TABLE1 and TABLE2.

Because my application uses the total interactions from TABLE2 if `didInteract` is true. I added the column `total` to TABLE1 so I wouldn't have to query all rows that match my criteria which could be costly. Therefore if a user interacts it performs two operations in the database. First, it creates a new interaction in TABLE2 if not already created and it increments the `total` interaction in TABLE1.

Does this logic make sense to do, or should I query TABLE2 to get the total (even if it may take a little longer) and remove the `total` column from TABLE1? Not sure if this passes 2NF although to me it sounds like an exception.

Comment: Your question is a case of premature optimization. You are asking for a solution to a perceived performance problem that could occur, but you have no data to back up this assertion. Before spending time on prematurely optimizing (and its attendant technical debt and impact on your development schedule), benchmark the performance. If the performance is acceptable by following good database practices (such as normalizing data), there's no benefit to going to the extra work of denormalizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically what you describe is denormalization. There's a risk of data anomalies with any denormalization. For example, if you add an interaction but forget to increment `TABLE1.total`, then the total will be inaccurate. But clients who query that total won't know that it's inaccurate unless they double-check by querying the aggregate count from `TABLE2`. If that double-check is necessary to be sure, then there's no point in storing the total.

There are legitimate cases where denormalization is helpful. If you can depend on it being accurate, or if you don't care if it's inaccurate from time to time, and you periodically re-initialize the total from the count of `TABLE2`, then it could be good enough.

There's also the question of whether the slowness of querying `TABLE2` directly is actually important. It's true that it's slower than querying the total as a precalculated count, but is the difference great enough that it makes your application fail its SLA?

These are tradeoffs, and which strategy is right for your app is up to you.